# HTML/CSS form field with suggestion

Tags: html, forms, field

What is it called or where can I find code for placing a 'suggestion' or grayed out text in a form field box that doesn't get pass as a value.  I know i can prepopulate it, but want to use it to only provide guidance.  Example, box that says "  "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
<input type=text disabled value='...'/>
```

(`disabled` wont pass the values, whereas `readonly` will pass the value)

Answer (score 1):

The terminology you're referring to is called a *watermark*.

There are many existing Javascript solutions written for this already, like [this one](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/).

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript will do this. I've used the jQuery framework, for example:

Setting the value:

```
    $('#comment_box').val('Optional comment..');
```

On click, removing the value:

```
    $('#comment_box').val('');
```

On submit:

```
    if (comment == 'Optional comment..'){
        comment = '';
    }
```

And submit your comment. I've left out the functions here but you can get an idea.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 has a [placeholder attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) supported by many modern browsers.

(But alas not MSIE.)

The above-linked article explains how to test for support and implement a javascript fallback.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are referring to is a watermark

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx

or

there are jquery defaultvalue plugins